# video/3gpp and video/quicktime MIME type in input file accept not working in chrome

Tags: html, web-frontend

I am using the following input element in my web page,

```
<input type="file" accept="video/mp4,video/quicktime,video/3gpp," multiple="multiple">
```

When I try to open a file using this input element in Chrome (v62 on Ubuntu), it fiters mp4 files, but the **3GP and MOV files aren't getting filtered**. It only shows the MP4 files in the folder.

I have cross checked the MIME types and can not figue out the issue.

Note: The code is working fine in Firefox

Comment: Works on my mac... IIRC Chrome does use the OS MIME type dictionary to make the association between file extensions and MIME types. Are you sure your extensions are well registered at the OS level? Also, you could probably workaround that by specifying manually the files extensions.

Comment: Here is the [apache list](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types) of extensions for your 3 MIMEs : `accept=".mp4,.mp4v,.mpg4,.3gp,.mov"`

Comment: I also checked on mac, it's working fine. 
The issue is with chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: And did you tried the extensions instead? I don't have an ubuntu to try this out, but following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/478029/adding-mimetypes-in-ubuntu-14-04), you should have  a `~/.local/share/mime/packages/` directory. Does this directory have an `video-3gpp.xml` file?

Comment: Adding extensions wont be helpful, as this will fix issue on my system, but what I want is to fix the issue on client's systems.

Comment: good to see all problems don't need to be fixed in an 6 to 8 minutes frame ;-) Did you tried the extension workaround I mentionned previously? (`.mp4, .mp4v,.mpg4,.3gp,.mov`). If you combine this with what you already have you should get as crossbrowser solution as you can get.